# How to set alt attribute for an <a> tag when it contains an image URL?

Tags: html, seo

Here is my code:

```
<a itemprop='image' target='_blank' href='http://lamtakam.com/img/post/imageGenerator.php?tc=17&id=321780&t=%D8%B3%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%85'>show</a>
```

See? It is a `<a>` tag which contains the URL of an image. That's why I've set `itemprop='image'` to it and fortunately, Google detects it as well.

[image]

All I want to know, how can I also set a text to that image? Something like `alt` attribute?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. `<a>` elements are containers, not replaced content. There don't have any intrinsic content to show an alternative to.

Comment: well ok, thanks .. just any idea how can I make it seo friendly? that's an image, how can I assign some words for it?

Comment: `<a href...>something more descriptive than the word "show"</a>`

Answer (score 0):

As @Quentin points out, you cannot use  `<a>` in this way.

You can however wrap `<a></a>` around `<img>`.  For example you can use

```
<a itemprop='image' target='_blank' rel='noopener noreferrer' href='http://lamtakam.com/img/post/imageGenerator.php?tc=17&id=321780&t=%D8%B3%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%85'><img src='example-image.gif' alt='Example image' height='42' width='42'></a>
```

Notice the `rel='noopener noreferrer'` in there?  If you use `target='_blank'` you should use `rel='noopener noreferrer'` to prevent the phishing attack called [reverse tabnabbing](https://mathiasbynens.github.io/rel-noopener/).